# Mac mini won't turn on after outage?

Tags: mac, power, desktop-computer

I turned off the electricity in the entire place to fix something but I forgot that my Mac Mini was on. When I turned the electricity back on, my mac mini wouldn't start. I tried:

- Removing all of the cables plugged in it
- I tested the wall outlet, there's electricity there
- I've clicked on the power button for 10 seconds, nothing happened
- The led light is not on
- There's no sound indicating that it's starting

I don't know what to do. It was working before that. Perfectly fine, now its not turning on. I have a new set of RAM installed (couple months ago) and an SSD instead of the typical HD. It's the 2012 Mac mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just in case someone has the same problem in future. I left the mini in the hands of a tech guy who couldn't figure it out. But then, someone on Apple discussions pointed out how to solve this issue.

Basically you leave it unplugged for a night, plugged in it, press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> along with the power button of the Mac mini.

Now, this might not work right away. If it doesn't work right away, unplugged it from the wall again, leave it for 5 min, then plugged it back in and try it again.

The person who mentioned this said it took 4 days and over 200 tries before it turned back on. For me, it took 2 tries and it worked.

This is also why it happens:

> The EFI firmware on the pram has been corrupted and the instruction to start the computer is not being properly executed. EFI firmware is the same as the BIOS on a windows machine

Kuddos to [Lemas](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32501504). All credit goes to that user.