# Why is my Mac mini not booting up?

Tags: boot, mac, power-supply, mac-mini

[I had issues in the past](https://superuser.com/a/1265416/167207) where after a power failure and sudden turn off, the Mac mini just won't start again (despite trying PRAM/SMC reset, giving it to technicians to test it) it just not working properly. The mini is awesome, it's fast (SSD), it's 2012, latest Mac OS X, i7.

The only solution was to buy a UPS and set it up so that if there's a power failure, the Mac mini would turn itself off when the UPS battery reaches 30%.

Today I had electricity issues. I turned the Mac mini off myself. After finally solving all electricity issues, the Mac mini won't start, yet again. I seriously don't know what do with it anymore. Apple services stores basically told me that there are no parts for the Mac mini here (I live in Bulgaria) and basically they can't do anything.

Something worth mentioning, last time this happened, I gave it to a friend who is an IT guy. He guy disassembled it, replaced my mini's power supply with another one, my Mac mini didn't turn on (no sound, no blinking light, no fan, nothing), then placed the old/original power supply back on an it worked. No idea what's the issue there.

What do I do??? Any advice would be welcome because I cannot give to a technicians anymore because they told me that they don't even have spare parts to try to replace my mini's parts and see if the problem is there.

Comment: Best guess, PRAM battery - nasty job... but it's just the right age that it's the most likely  https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Late+2012+PRAM+Battery+Replacement/11725

Comment: Last technician who tested it said that he tested the battery and he said it will lasts years ahead but apparently it's not that.

Comment: If he got that far into an 8-year-old machine & didn't take the opportunity to change a $1 component with an expected 6 - 8 year life expectancy while he was there... :/ Failing PRAM batteries can cause all kinds of weird issues - including yours. Your linked issue I'd have also said replace the battery [I didn't see it at the time]

Comment: Maybe I'll just do it myself. I got your link, so, I'll just do it myself and see if that would fix the issue

Comment: I wish you luck. Come back & tell us how it went. Tag me using "@Tetsujin" in a comment, so I'll be notified of your reply.

Comment: @Tetsujin I managed to start it up. Bless you for the idea. Tbh, it was a nightmare to change the battery because my screws are practically screwed. But I managed to do it and it actually worked! I don't know if that solves the problem permanently, but it did work

Comment: Glad it worked. I do think that ought to be your long-term solution. I had a Mac last year with some very random misbehaviours, including ones similar to yours. New Battery & it's been absolutely fine ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments... this was just a gut feeling that did turn out to be right.
The symptoms, random as they appeared to be over two distinct questions, added up to the same solution.

Replace the PRAM Battery.

Instructions [Difficulty level - Difficult] at [iFixit - Mac Mini Late 2012 PRAM Battery Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+Mini+Late+2012+PRAM+Battery+Replacement/11725)

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for letting me know and I actually decided to do it (honestly, I really thought it wasn't it haha). But bless you! I hope this help more people if they experience the same problem!